# Does it matter if a database table column is nullable even though it's mandatory that it's not empty if I'm using validation on the back-end?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm thinking about merging the following 2 tables:

```
Table: images
Columns: id, name, description, user_id, file_name, upvotes, downvotes, views

Table: album_images
Columns: id, album_id, file_name
```

What I am worried about is that if I merge them, I'd have to make name, description, upvotes, downvotes and views nullable since album_images don't have that information but my images should definitely have those.

I am validating the information from the HTML forms.

Comment: The current structure allows you to have multiple images per album (which I would expect from the word "album"), if you merge them, you'll have all of the information for the albums duplicated for every image you put in the album. This is just a headache for several reasons, including if you want to change anything about the album you'll have to update all of the rows that contain that data. I don't suggest you do this.

Comment: Why would you have to make them nullable? If you merge them, you'll have to duplicate the data, not leave it null. As @GrumpyCrouton said, this denormalization is poor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself this question: what is the advantage of merging the tables?

The disadvantage is obvious.  With two tables, your DBMS can enforce relational integrity: required values that must be present, else the row is rejected.  It's foolproof.  That enforcement holds no matter where else it might be checked.

If you want a "single table" so you can query both tables at once, that's why views were invented.  Create a view that is the UNION of both tables, and use that.

As programmers, we learn to factor out redundancy.  The temptation is sometimes to see redundancy and say, "hey, I can merge these two".  In an SQL database, though, that instinct is backwards: in SQL, redundancy is often eliminated by *adding* tables, not removing them.

Looking at your column names, I wonder if `file_name` refers to image files in both tables, the image denoted by `id`?  If so, you could eliminate redundancy -- and so improve referential integrity -- by eliminating `album_images.file_name`. If you need the filename for the image of an album, that's what JOIN is for.